# Typescript: Propiedad de tipo basado en "key" del objeto

Tags: typescript

Hola buenas tardes compañeros, estoy trabajando en un componente genérico y por ende haciendo una interfaz que tiene una propiedad "key" de tipo string que pertenece al objeto genérico, hasta ahí todo bien, pero también requiero una propiedad que solicite una funcion "parse" que obtenga una funcion que de parámetro tenga el tipo de la propiedad "key".

Les comparto lo que tengo a ver si pueden ayudarme, se los agradecería:

```js
 
type StringKeys<T> = Extract<keyof T, string>;
type OnlyOptionPropertiesKeys<T extends OpcionEntity> = Omit<T, keyof OpcionEntity>;
type OnlyOptionPropertiesAsString<T extends OpcionEntity> = StringKeys<OnlyOptionPropertiesKeys<T>>;
type ValueOfProperty<T extends OpcionEntity> = T[keyof T];

export interface OpcionTableHeader<T extends OpcionEntity>{
    key: OnlyOptionPropertiesAsString<T>;
    parse?: (value: ValueOfProperty<T>) => ValueOfProperty<T> | string;
}

export default abstract class OpcionEntity {
    Id: number;
    constructor(Id: number){
      this.Id = Id;
    }
}

class ConceptoCXP extends OpcionEntity {
    Usuario: number;

    constructor(Id:number, Usuario: number){
      super(Id);
      this.Usuario = Usuario;
    }
}
```

Todo bien como lo tengo, pero no me muestra el tipo que quisiera en concreto en el typescript:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que me mostrara el tipo: `value: number` que es el tipo en concreto de `ConceptoCXP['Usuario']`

Comment: Muestra la definición de `ConceptoCPX` y `OpcionEntity`

Comment: @g.4 Ya agregué las clases faltantes,